# Identify sub-lists of a list by using loop

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list as below:
 `[34, 23, 34, 323, 2343, 23, [324, 3434, 232], 34343, 5343, 3434, 3434, 33, 3654, 22]`

I want to filter out the sub-list within the list by using loop. How should I do it?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: do you want to **sort** or **filter out**?

Answer (score 0):

What about using a list comprehension with [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) and [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
L = [34, 23, 34, 323, 2343, 23, [324, 3434, 232], 34343,
     5343, 3434, 3434, 33, 3654, 22]

out = [sorted(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x for x in L]
```

output:

```
[34, 23, 34, 323, 2343, 23, [232, 324, 3434], 34343,
 5343, 3434, 3434, 33, 3654, 22]
```

###### filtering out the sublists

if you want to **filter out** (= remove) the sublists, use:

```
out = [x for x in L if not isinstance(x, list)]
```

output:

```
[34, 23, 34, 323, 2343, 23, 34343, 5343, 3434, 3434, 33, 3654, 22]
```

In any case, the core logic is to use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance), to identify the lists.

Comment: Pretty sure "sort out" means either "find out which are the lists", or "remove the lists", but not actually "sort the lists". Might be mistaken, of course.

Comment: @tobias_kI just thought of that and asked for clarification (I'll add an alternative)